# select query inside a while loop

Tags: java, hashmap, resultset

I have a SELECT query inside a While loop. I am expecting a single row. After getting that row I want to come out of the while loop. The problem is, after the first iteration when I execute the select query and check the resultset, I am getting "Invalid Cursor" error. Not sure what wrong I am doing here.

```
//looping thru hashmap

Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    int bind_index=1; 
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    log.debug(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());

    String sql_main = null;
    sql_main = getSql(sb2.toString());
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement p_stmt1 = null;
    p_stmt1 = db.getPreparedStatement(sql_main);    

    p_stmt1.setString(bind_index++, (String)pair.getKey()); 
    p_stmt1.setString(bind_index++, (String)pair.getValue());   
    p_stmt1.setString(bind_index++,strGMTDate+" "+strGMTTime);
    p_stmt1.setString(bind_index++,strGMTDate+" "+strGMTTime);
    resultSet = db.executeQuery(p_stmt1);


    CachedRowSetImpl rsCopy2 = new CachedRowSetImpl();  
    rsCopy2.populate(resultSet);    
    if(rsCopy2.next()){
        rsCopy2.beforeFirst();
        grid.bind(rsCopy2);
        break;
    }
    resultSet = null;
    p_stmt1=null;
    resultSet.close();
    p_stmt1.close();
}
```

Comment: Why in the first place are you looping if you want to exit the loop on the first iteration? Also if you ever reach the `resultSet.close()` statement, you will get an `NPE`.

Comment: I want to exit the loop if the resultset has row, or else the iteration will continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since your SQL doesn't change, you should prepare the statement outside your loop. Also, you should use try-with-resources to ensure JDBC resources are cleaned up.

Also, your `executeQuery` was wrong.

```
String sql_main = getSql(sb2.toString());
try (PreparedStatement p_stmt1 = db.getPreparedStatement(sql_main)) {
    for (Map.Entry pair : map.entrySet()) {
        log.debug(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        int bind_index = 0;
        p_stmt1.setString(++bind_index, (String)pair.getKey());
        p_stmt1.setString(++bind_index, (String)pair.getValue());
        p_stmt1.setString(++bind_index, strGMTDate + " " + strGMTTime);
        p_stmt1.setString(++bind_index, strGMTDate + " " + strGMTTime);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = p_stmt1.executeQuery()) {
            if (resultSet.next()) {

                // Capture/use values from resultSet here

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still have a problem, I need to pass the resultset to another class method. Here is what I am doing, if (resultSet.next()) {
         resultSet.beforeFirst();
         grid.bind(resultSet);
         break;
        } But I am getting "Unsupported method for a forward-only result set." error.

Comment: As soon as you exit the code segment, the `ResultSet` and the `PreparedStatement` gets closed, so you have to consume the data inside that `if` statement, e.g. by constructing a Data object with all the values you need, hence isolating the use of the `ResultSet`. Code isolation is an often recommended practice.